# Read from the specific position by readBytes function in flex

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4, flex3, arrays

I am trying to do some operation on text file. What I am doing is below:

Reading a file using the code below:

```
var data:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
var inFile:File = File.desktopDirectory;
inFile = inFile.resolvePath('dummy.txt');
var inStream:FileStream = new FileStream();

inStream.open(inFile, FileMode.READ);
inStream.readBytes(data, 0, data.length);
inStream.close();
```

Suppose dummy.txt file has the text abcdefghi123456789 - which has a data length of 18 characters.

**Case 1**

If I want to read the entire file, I use this code

`inStream.readBytes(data, 0, data.length);`

This returns the full file data successfully.

**Case 2**:

I want to read only the characters 12345 and store them in a byteArray, I am trying to pass offSet like in the code below

`inStream.readBytes(data, 9, 5);`

It returns an error the following data -

`___12345`

That is 9 spaces and then the 5 characters, when it should ideally return only the 5 characters.

So how can I do this. Any sample code and web link would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `offset` argument of the `readBytes` method specifies the offset into the output `ByteArray`, not the file. You can seek in a `FileStream` by setting the `position` property. Try the following:

```
inStream.position = 9;
inStream.readBytes(data, 0, 5);
```

Comment: It is returning "abcde" but I need 12345.
Thanks for reply. But how can I get 12345?

Comment: try this public function set position(value:Number):void
More details about the position property here - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7da7.html